# Why can a MultiSig transaction fail on too many signers?

Tags: multi-sig

The doc is clear what happens but has anybody some use cases **why** this should happen?

> Once the signature threshold is met if there are any leftover signatures then the transaction is regarded as having **too many signatures** which results in a **failed transaction** even if the remaining signatures are valid, i.e. for a transaction signed with N signatures, if the threshold is reached using K signatures then the transaction will fail if N > K.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#thresholds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Signatures verification consume significant CPU resources. Of course, using a dozen of signitures for each submitted transaction won't result in the network congestion, however it can slow down ledger closing. Therefore, it's rather a protection from lazy developers which may tend to use as many signers as possible in multisig schemes in order to avoid coding elaborate algorithms and dealing with thresholds.

Comment: Each superfluous signature also adds 64 bytes to the blockchain, *forever*

Comment: @JohanStén Good point! It's even more important than validators' CPU resources.

Comment: For reference see here: https://github.com/stellar/docs/issues/387

Comment: Has that worst case scenario ever happened? We're talking collisions of 32-bit values, where we have a maximum of 20 hints within a transaction envelope. That's a one in a 20 million occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess: To clear any doubt about who exactly is in charge of a transaction. It would not make a technical difference if a 2-of-3 transaction is signed by [A,B], [B,C], [A,C] or [A,B,C] and even common sense would be like "so what, then just every signer is responsible", I can imagine that some legal conditions might get unnecessarily complicated when a transaction was signed by three parties altough it was only required to be signed by two.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is performance related, as unnecessary signature verification has a large effect on performance before accepting transactions in consensus.